# Travel-oriented map program or app built around advanced queries and relevant data

Tags: maps, search, travel

Google Maps and Apple Maps are both missing something critical for cities: public transit stations.

I opened up Apple Maps and all of the transit (train/bus) stations are missing. There's no UI option to enable them and no preferences menu.

A Google search only turned up "transit stations on route to and directions" which aren't useful when looking for a query such as "Find all hotels in a given area within 1 mile of a train station". Am I supposed to get a list of hotels and then manually type in each one and route to a train station? Ridiculous.

The new Google Maps UI is mentally retarded. The top of the web UI (for hotel search) is a feature-starved search bar with on check in/out, number of guests, price, user rating and hotel type, and on-site amenities (Wi-Fi/free breakfast, restaurant/bar built in). The "Search Nearby button"? Gone. (dozens of angry users raging about it in https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/GqGuGPY9Xfc) The left third of the lower view is a list of hotels. Clicking on a hotel consumes the middle third for only partially relevant information, leaving a claustrophobic right third of the window for the map and forcing you to zoom in and pan to find anything.

With those obvious and incompetent blunders in mind, I'm looking for alternatives built for advanced users and queries with a good foundation of common sense. Preferably something like a Semantic Mediawiki geographic query instance (see https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Selecting_pages).

An example geographic query: {{#ask:[[Category:Hotel]] [[Has coordinates::[[Category:Restaurant]] (.2 miles)]] [[Has coordinates::[[Category:Train Station]] (1 mile)]] }}

translates to "Find all hotels within .2 miles of a restaurant and also within 1 mile of a train station". If hotels actively tag themselves with room, amenities, and price availability, you can get even more useful queries such as:

{{#ask:[[Category:Hotel]] [[Price::<200]] [[Has free breakfast::Yes]] [[Has free shuttle service::Yes]] [[Has coordinates::[[Category:Restaurant]] [[Average price::<6]] (.2 miles)]] [[Has coordinates::[[Category:Train Station]] [[Type::!Commuter]] (1 mile)]] }}

translates to "Find all hotels with cost per day <= 200 units (of the local currency) with free breakfast and a free shuttle service, with a restaurant within .2 miles of average meal price <= 6 units (local currency) and a non-commuter-rail train station within a mile.